# contenteditable in a table: select cells

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, function, select

I generate in php a table. Each cell have a distinct id made from the name of the column and the number of the row.

```
<tr>
    <td contenteditable="true" id="i-date-1">26/03/2014</td><td id="i-amount-1">200</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" id="i-date-2">26/04/2014</td><td id="i-amount-2">300</td>
</tr>
```

I want to record the changes in a sql database via jQuery. For that I need to add an eventListener to each cell, then call a function that would post the data to the server side php script, but I'm confused about how to do that, here's my try which doesn't work :

```
$(['id*="i-"']).each(function() {
            $(this).addEventListener("blur", updateFunction, false);
            $(this).spellcheck = 'true';
});
```

And then my update function :

```
function updateFunction()
{
    var lineID = $(this).attr(id);
    var needle = lineID.indexOf("-");
    needle = lineID.indexOf("-", needle);
    needle = needle + 1 ;
    lineID = lineID.substr(needle);
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "queries.php?q=update&iID="+lineID,
    });
}
```

1) am I doing right to add an eventListener to all cells or is there easier ?
2) my updateFunction is shitty, I know :) but I'm not experienced enough to figure out how to fix it... if anyone could help ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some changes it can work well, like this.

```
$("[id*='i-']").on("blur", updateFunction).prop('spellcheck', true);
function updateFunction()
{
  var lineID = $(this).attr('id');
  var needle = lineID.indexOf("-");
  needle = lineID.indexOf("-", needle);
  needle = needle + 1 ;
  lineID = lineID.substr(needle);
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "queries.php?q=update&iID="+lineID,
  });
}
```

Here is a demo **http://jsbin.com/nitewe/edit?js,output**

Instead of splitting ID, it will be easier to use `data-*` attribute to store additional information like `data-1` and `date-2`

```
<td contenteditable="true" class="i-date" data-date="date-1">26/03/2014</td><td class="i-amount">200</td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="i-date" data-date="date-2">26/04/2014</td><td class="i-amount">300</td>
```

With such a structure would simply the script to something like this

```
$(".i-date").on("blur", updateFunction).prop('spellcheck', true);
function updateFunction()
{
  var lineID = $(this).data('date');
  var amt = $(this).next('.i-amount');
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "queries.php?q=update&iID="+lineID,
  });
}
```

[`.next([selector])`](http://api.jquery.com/next) will get the reference to next sibling with class `.i-amount`.

Demo **http://jsbin.com/sucozu/edit?html,js,output**

Comment: Thanks, it's much better like that.... only one thing I don't figure out... now that we know the id of the line, I need to record all data, which means data in i-amount-1 also. Should I pass it as a parameter in my function or can I access it from my function ?

Comment: use classes for TDs having amount as well. Please see updated answer

Comment: ok, but one question, what does $(this).data('date') return ?

Comment: `$('selector').data()` (http://api.jquery.com/data/) returns the value of any `data-*` attribute. In this case since we have `data-date` attribute for td. $('...').data('date') will get the value in `data-date` attribute

Comment: oh ok, that's what I was thinking...so I still need to substr it to get the line nr or to just put 1 instead of data-1 in the data-date attribute. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: yes use `1` instead of substr. The code will be clear and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Keep value of the id as an attribute of

```
<td contenteditable="true"  dateId="date-1">26/03/2014</td><td id="i-amount-1">200</td>
<td contenteditable="true"  dateId="date-2">26/04/2014</td><td id="i-amount-2">300</td>

function updateFunction()
{
    lineID = $(this).attr('dateId');
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "queries.php?q=update&iID="+lineID,
    });
}
```